# high-order functions in ML

Tags: ml

struggling to understand high-order functions in ml.

```
> fn a => fn b => fn c => (a c,b c);
val it = fn: ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b * 'c
```

can someone explain to me how this work. I do not understand how "a" goes to "c" for the second part. I believe the output should be:

```
val it = fn:  a -> b -> c -> a * c -> b * c
```

?

Comment: This reeks to homework

Comment: i do not see how this is a homework considering  that i provided solution to the answer, but i just do not get how the output was execute that way. Well it doesn't have to be this function types, can use any other if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` are clearly functions, so `'a` and `'b` are too general types for them.
Also, `(a c, b c)` is a pair, but you've given it the type `'a * 'c -> 'b * 'c` - a function from pairs to pairs.

Let's rename things in the function in order to keep the names of the parameters  more easily distinguishable from their types:

```
> fn x => fn y => fn z => (x z, y z);
val it = fn: ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b * 'c
```

When you're determining a function's type, it's usually a good idea to start with the result and work your way backwards towards the parameters.

It's pretty obvious that this result, `(x z, y z)`, is a pair.
Let's say its type is `P * Q` - that is, `x z` is a `P`, and `y z` is a `Q`.
We know (from `x z` and `y z`) that both `x` and `y` are functions, and if the type of `z` is `R`, we have

```
x : R -> P
y : R -> Q
```

Filling this in we have the type

```
(R -> P) -> (R -> Q) -> R -> P * Q
   x           y        z    result
```

which we can rename as

```
('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b * 'c
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition for @molbdnilo's answer: notice that "->" is right associative